# nodejs using promises to handle multiple callbacks

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

and am trying to learn about the how to async or promises or anything to make my code better. here's an example of my code

```
Bus.findOne({_id: bus_id}, function (err, bus) {
if (err) {
    res.json({status: "error", message: "please enter a valid bus_id"});
    return;
}
bus.language = record.language ? record.language : bus.language;
bus.bus_number = record.bus_number  ? record.bus_number : bus.bus_number;
bus.bus_driver = bus_driver ? bus_driver : bus.bus_driver;
bus.bus_details = bus_details ? bus_details : bus.bus_details;
bus.trips = record.trips ? record.trips : bus.trips;
bus.location = record.location ? record.location : bus.location;
bus.save(function (err, bus) {
    if (err) {
        res.json({status: "error", error: errors, message: "bus wasn't saved"});
        return;
    } else {
        User.findOne({refid:bus_id},function(err,doc){
            if (err) {
                res.json({status: "error", error: "bus user update was not saved"});
                return;
            } else if(doc){
                doc.name =  "bus number"+ '' + bus.bus_number;
                doc.refid = bus.id;
                doc.save(function(err){
                    if (err) {
                        res.json({status: "error", error: "bus user update was not saved"});
                        return;
                    }else{
                        res.json({status: "success", message: "bus was successfully updated", bus: bus});
                        return;
                    }
                });
            }else{
                res.json({status:"error",message:"an error with finding user"});
                return;
            }
        });
    }
});
  });
```

this is what i ended up with

```
Bus.findOne({_id:bus_id}).exec().then(function(bus){
    bus.language = record.language ? record.language : bus.language;
    bus.bus_number = record.bus_number  ? record.bus_number : bus.bus_number;
    bus.bus_driver = bus_driver ? bus_driver : bus.bus_driver;
    bus.bus_details = bus_details ? bus_details : bus.bus_details;
    bus.trips = record.trips ? record.trips : bus.trips;
    bus.location = record.location ? record.location : bus.location;
    return bus.save().exec();
}).then(function(bus){
    return User.findOne({refid:bus._id}).exec();
}).then(function(doc){
    doc.name =  "bus number"+ '' + bus.bus_number;
    doc.refid = bus.id;
    return User.save().exec();
}).then(function(){
    res.json({status:"success",message:"bus and associated user has been removed"});
}).catch(function(error){
    res.json({status:"error",message:"an error with finding user"});
});
```

but the server keeps catching errors, i know i did something wrong but i dont know where the error is

Comment: You are getting the error parameter in your catch. Why don't you try printing that and seeing what the error is.

Comment: TypeError: bus.save(...).exec is not a function
    at C:\WebstormProjects\smartschool\routes\buses.js:196:30
    at newTickHandler (C:\WebstormProjects\smartschool\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:234:18)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Comment: `bus.save()` should return a promise. I don't think you need to append the `exec()` after the `save()` function.